# Default value for Redux-thunk input

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have a simple SPA with thunk. It uses github API to get a list of repos.
I had previously an example with class presentational component. It had a local state, but I decided to simplify example as much as possible and refactored it to function and removed local state and using ref to get input value. It works fine

1. How to set the default value in input field, so that when the app loads it gets that value.
2. I don't quite understand how to remove combineReducers and use a single reducer as when I use createStore with single reducer app breaks

Here is the code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/k13nowrj33

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { applyMiddleware, combineReducers, createStore } from "redux";
import { connect, Provider } from "react-redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import "./index.css";

// actions.js
const addRepos = repos => ({ type: "ADD_REPOS", repos });
const clearRepos = () => ({ type: "CLEAR_REPOS" });
const getRepos = username => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const url = `https://api.github.com/users/${username}/repos`;
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const responseBody = await response.json();
    dispatch(addRepos(responseBody));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    dispatch(clearRepos());
  }
};

// reducers.js
const repos = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_REPOS":
      return action.repos;
    case "CLEAR_REPOS":
      return [];
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const rootreducer = combineReducers({ repos });

const store = createStore(rootreducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

// App.js
function App(props) {
  var textInput;
  var setTextInputRef = element => { textInput = element; };
  var submit = () => props.getRepos(textInput.value);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Github username: </h1>
      <input type="text" ref={setTextInputRef} />
      <button onClick={submit}>Get All Repos</button>
      <ul>
        {props.repos.map((repo, index) => (<li key={index}><a href={repo.html_url}>{repo.name}</a></li> ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

// AppContainer.js
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ repos: state.repos });
const mapDispatchToProps = { getRepos };
const AppContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><AppContainer /></Provider>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: What's the default input value meant to be?

Comment: Just any github username that goes like a string. For example -  mapledrive

Comment: what do you mean "the app breaks". What exactly happens? If you don't use `combineReducers` your store state will have a different shape, so you must also change the `mapStateToProps` function. Seems you might want to pass the entire state as props. `const mapStateToProps = state => state`.

Comment: When I write const store = createStore(repos, applyMiddleware(thunk)); typeerror tells props.repos is undefined

Comment: Yeah. So check the stack trace. If you want the entire state to be passed as a prop called repos, you can do `mapStateToProps = state => ({repos: state})`.

Comment: The default value for the input depends on whether you want an uncontrolled or controlled component. It's explained in the react docs. https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values

Comment: Thanks I understand now. I changed mapstatetoprops so that whole state goes in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) You can use `defaultValue` for this purpose.

2.) As mentioned in the comments, if you don't use `combineReducers()` you'll need to change your `mapStateToProps()`.

Here's one way to do it:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { applyMiddleware, combineReducers, createStore } from "redux";
import { connect, Provider } from "react-redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import "./index.css";

// actions.js
const addRepos = repos => ({ type: "ADD_REPOS", repos });
const clearRepos = () => ({ type: "CLEAR_REPOS" });
const getRepos = username => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const url = `https://api.github.com/users/${username}/repos`;
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const responseBody = await response.json();
    dispatch(addRepos(responseBody));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    dispatch(clearRepos());
  }
};

// reducers.js
const repos = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_REPOS":
      return action.repos;
    case "CLEAR_REPOS":
      return [];
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const store = createStore(repos, applyMiddleware(thunk));

// App.js
function App(props) {
  var textInput;
  var setTextInputRef = element => {
    textInput = element;
  };
  var submit = () => props.getRepos(textInput.value);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Github username: </h1>
      <input defaultValue="colinricardo" type="text" ref={setTextInputRef} />
      <button onClick={submit}>Get All Repos</button>
      <ul>
        {props.repos.map((repo, index) => (
          <li key={index}>
            <a href={repo.html_url}>{repo.name}</a>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

// AppContainer.js
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ repos: state });

const mapDispatchToProps = { getRepos };
const AppContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <AppContainer />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

CodeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/mooj24l4mx).

To get repos on load:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { applyMiddleware, combineReducers, createStore } from "redux";
import { connect, Provider } from "react-redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import "./index.css";

// actions.js
const addRepos = repos => ({ type: "ADD_REPOS", repos });
const clearRepos = () => ({ type: "CLEAR_REPOS" });
const getRepos = username => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const url = `https://api.github.com/users/${username}/repos`;
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const responseBody = await response.json();
    dispatch(addRepos(responseBody));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    dispatch(clearRepos());
  }
};

// reducers.js
const repos = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_REPOS":
      return action.repos;
    case "CLEAR_REPOS":
      return [];
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const store = createStore(repos, applyMiddleware(thunk));

// App.js
class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.submit();
  }

  submit = () => this.props.getRepos(this.textInput.value);

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Github username: </h1>
        <input
          defaultValue="colinricardo"
          type="text"
          ref={ref => (this.textInput = ref)}
        />
        <button onClick={this.submit}>Get All Repos</button>
        <ul>
          {this.props.repos.map((repo, index) => (
            <li key={index}>
              <a href={repo.html_url}>{repo.name}</a>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
// AppContainer.js
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ repos: state });

const mapDispatchToProps = { getRepos };
const AppContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <AppContainer />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: I tried this and it shows default value in input. Such a pity it does not set the state with list of repos and consequently app does not render list of repos after app was loaded

Comment: I think you're getting a cached version. Try it in incognito!

Comment: I tried in vain. I think there should be some default action sent to reducer when app loads

Comment: Oh, my bad - you mean to have them already loaded when app loads. You can just change to a class component and run the `submit()` in `componentDidMount()`. Edit: I've added this code to the answer, and CodeSandbox is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/y20x70l7x9

Comment: It is simple with class. How to make it with function. I initially started with class and there was local state. So I decided to simplify it. My idea was that to keep all the logic outside of presentational component. so your example is fantastic, but it makes use of class component

Comment: If you can use a newer version of React, then you can use hooks to get the same effect. Otherwise, you can't use lifecycle methods outside of a class.

Comment: Oh really, I must read about this.Thanks for help it is great

Comment: Sure thing :) What you want is the `useEffect()` hook, which you can use similar to `componentDidMount()`.